# Is a *.wordpress.com blog easy to migrate?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, migration, domain

As a student software developer who is about to graduate, I find it is time to start my own blog. I've been told it is important to make a name for yourself, to stand out from the rest. Therefore I decided to make a Wordpress website.

Since I live in Belgium, I would like a `.be` domain. But, I'm new to Wordpress and I want to go full-on with my own theme from the start. However, I would like to avoid the cost of my domain during the development phase of my website, so I'm planning to create it on the free `*.wordpress.com` domain first.

### My question:

If I do this, will I have an easy time migrating everything to my own domain? Which features of my web hoster (server, database, disk space, etc) should I look for specifically, to make the process go smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple..

### Export

[image]

Just check this page to export your blog data..

http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/

### Import

Install a fresh wordpress.. Then import it..

[image]

http://en.support.wordpress.com/import/

### Please note:

wordpress.com uses the same software downloaded from wordpress.org.. They just using it as multisite..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Thanks, it's even more simple than I thought :) I encountered something on the site on the topic of migration, and it said when the URL of your site changed, you needed to replace it everywhere in the database and also in serialized data. So I won't have to do all that then?

Comment: That only applicable for self hosted wordpress sites. You can only export the data as XML file using wordpress.com.. I mean you will not get any MySQL datas from wordpress.com